# value is match with xml element then return all there sibling attribute value.

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

i am try to get all attribute value if attribute value in my xml file.

```
i am try this  xpath:-
var xPath = '//*[local-name() = "dist_region" and ' +
                                        ' contains(concat(@value, ","), "' + array_top[i] + ',")]' + 
                                        '/preceding-sibling::*/@*';
```

but its return me top of node .
when entered value is match then its return there above all attribute value.
 
but i want to all there sibling attribute value.
this is my ml format:-

```
<products>
  <product_id value="1">
    <tab_id value="351">
      <tab_name value="test1"/>
      <region_timezone value="1"/>
      <registrationstatus value="2"/>
      <eventstatus value="2"/>
      <dist_activity value="4"/>
      <dist_activity value="10066"/>
      <dist_activity value="10070"/>
      <dist_region value="4909"/>
      <dist_region value="4902"/>
      <dist_region value="4905"/>
      <dist_value value="55"/>
      <dist_value value="342"/>
      <dist_value value="86"/>
   </tab_id>
 </product_id>
<product_id value="2">
    <tab_id value="351">
      <tab_name value="test1"/>
      <region_timezone value="1"/>
      <registrationstatus value="2"/>
      <eventstatus value="2"/>
      <dist_activity value="4"/>
      <dist_activity value="10066"/>
      <dist_activity value="10070"/>
      <dist_region value="4912"/>
      <dist_region value="4908"/>
      <dist_region value="4901"/>
      <dist_value value="55"/>
      <dist_value value="342"/>
      <dist_value value="86"/>
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
</products>
```

Present output is:-

```
test1,1,2,2,4,10066,10070
```

expected Output:-

```
1,351,test1,1,2,2,4,10066,10070,4909,4902,4905,55,342,86
```

how can i get all attribute value please solve this query.
thanks.

Comment: How to choose the `<product_id/>` element (so why choose the first, but not the second)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly changing your xapht will do.
Replace `/preceding-sibling::*`  with `/ancestor::product_id/descendant-or-self::*`.

Explanation **what you did:**

```
'//*[local-name() = "dist_region" and  contains(concat(@value, ","), "' + array_top[i] + ',")]'
```

You are looking for a  **dist_region**  with a given value in attribute value. This would be for example the element `<dist_region value="4909"/>`.
Next step for this element is `'/preceding-sibling::*/@*`
Which are all attribute values from all element are in document order before the current element on the same level. Which leads to the output you see.

**What you should do:**
Because of your statement **expected Output:-**
It seems you like to get all attributes of the product_id  where the current dist_region belongs to. Therefore use:

```
ancestor::product_id/descendant-or-self::*/@*
```

Because:
`ancestor::product_id` find product_id *above* form current element.
and next step `descendant-or-self::*/@*` find any attribute in any child in any deep.
**That's it.**

Somme additional commands:
I do not know why your are using `//*[local-name() = "dist_region" and ...]`
`//dist_region[...]/` should do the same.

Output:

```
 1 351 test1 1 2 2 4 10066 10070 4909 4902 4905 55 342 86
```

Comment: hey if i want to need local name them its possible...? like Product_id=1,test_id=251,...etc

Comment: For example, ff you are looking for Product_id with attribute "value" is "1" use: `//Product_id[@id='1']` or `//Product_id[test_id/@id='251']`.

Comment: if i want only `<region_timezone value="1"/>` then what i want to change?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. To get the value of region_timezone  in a selected Product_id:`//Product_id[@id='1']//region_timezone/@value ` or to select the Product_id with a given region_timezone value: `//Product_id[*/region_timezone/@value ='1']/`...

Comment: check this i am update new question with full code:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584187/if-element-attribute-value-match-then-get-image-attribute-value