# if element attribute value match then get image attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath

i am try to get element image attribute.
from this xml file:-

```
<products>
      <product_id value="1">
        <tab_id value="351">
          <tab_name value="test1"/>
          <region_timezone value="1"/>
          <registrationstatus value="2"/>
          <eventstatus value="2"/>
          <dist_activity value="4"/>
          <dist_activity value="10066"/>
          <dist_activity value="10070"/>
          <dist_region value="4909"/>
          <dist_region value="4902"/>
          <dist_region value="4905"/>
          <dist_value value="55"/>
          <dist_value value="342"/>
          <dist_value value="86"/>
          <image value="female.jpg"/>
       </tab_id>
     </product_id>
    <product_id value="2">
        <tab_id value="351">
          <tab_name value="test1"/>
          <region_timezone value="1"/>
          <registrationstatus value="2"/>
          <eventstatus value="2"/>
          <dist_activity value="4"/>
          <dist_activity value="10066"/>
          <dist_activity value="10070"/>
          <dist_region value="4912"/>
          <dist_region value="4908"/>
          <dist_region value="4901"/>
          <dist_value value="55"/>
          <dist_value value="342"/>
          <dist_value value="86"/>
          <image value="male.jpg"/>
        </tab_id>
      </product_id>
    </products>
```

and this is my xpath:-

```
var xPath = '//*[local-name() = "dist_region" and ' +
                                        ' contains(concat(@value, ","), "' + array_top[i] + ',")]' + 
                                        '//Product_id[/image]/@value';
```

this is full code:-

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var comma='';
    var node='';
    var result='';
    var output;

        var xml;
        $.get(
        "product.xml",
        null,
        function (data) {
            xml = data;
        },
        "xml"
    );
        function get_list() {
            var value = "4909,4902,4905";
            var array_top = value.split(',');
            for(var i=0;i<array_top.length;i++)
            {
                var xPath = '//*[local-name() = "dist_region" and ' +
                                        ' contains(concat(@value, ","), "' + array_top[i] + ',")]' + 
                                        '//Product_id[/image]/@value';
                                        alert(array_top[i]);
                    var iterator = xml.evaluate(xPath, xml.documentElement, null,
                            XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
                            var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
                            while (thisNode) {
                    node = thisNode.textContent;
                    thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
                                result+= comma+node;
                                comma=',';

                            }
                            }
            output = result;
            alert(output);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Search" onclick="get_list()">
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

expected O/p:-
`female.jpg,male.jpg`

here i am try to pass one by one dist_region value from the array and if its match on my xml file then return there image element attribute value.
please check my x-path and suggest me.
thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you print out your xpath after you have constructed it. In that way it will be clearer what it is doing. Note that xpath is case sensitive; you have a `product_id`, not  `'//Product_id[/image]/@value';`

Comment: @peter.murray.rust i want to `female.jpg,male.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the xapth point of this seem to be what you are looking for:

```
'//product_id [*/dist_region[contains(concat(@value, ","), $array_top )]]/tab_id/image/@value'
```

which should be something like this wiht your javasrcipt var:

```
'//product_id [*/dist_region[contains(concat(@value, ","), '
 + array_top[i] + 
')]]/tab_id/image/@value'
```

Still I do not know why you need the contains().
Try also:

```
'//product_id [*/dist_region[@value = $array_top ]]/tab_id/image/@value'
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand the question fully, but according to your code, the values you're looking for are: "4909,4902,4905", doesn't that mean it should return female.jpg, female.jpg, female.jpg?

You can use this xpath to find the image file that is a sibling of the dist_region (just replace the '4909' with other numbers:

```
//dist_region[@value='4909']/following-sibling::image
```

Answer (score 1):

The XPATH which you have written `//Product_id[/image]/@value` is wrong use //Product_id/tab_id/image/@value to get `female.jpg, and male.jpg`